# Efficient way to consume messages in parallel in .NET

Tags: .net, events, parallel-processing, messaging, actor

I have a stream of messages and based on some criteria I want each consumer to be able to process some of them in parallel. Each consumer should be able to subscribe and unsubscribe dynamically.

[image]

A little bit more information about the input:

- I receive around 500 messages per second
- I have around 15000 consumers

So far I have several solutions:

1. Events.

```
public class Message
{
    public Message(int id, string data)
    {
        Id = id;
        Data = data;
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    public string Data { get; }
}

public class ConsumersDispatcher
{
    public event EventHandler<Message> MessageReceived;

    public ConsumersDispatcher(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    public void OnMessageReceived(Message message)
    {
        if (MessageReceived == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var delegates = MessageReceived.GetInvocationList();

        Parallel.ForEach(delegates, d => d.DynamicInvoke(this, message));
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    private readonly ICollection<ConsumersDispatcher> _dispatchers;

    public Consumer(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        _dispatchers = new List<ConsumersDispatcher>();
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public void Subscribe(ConsumersDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        if (_dispatchers.Any(m => m.Id == dispatcher.Id))
        {
            return;
        }

        _dispatchers.Add(dispatcher);
        dispatcher.MessageReceived += Foo;
    }

    private void Foo(object sender, Message message)
    {
        // process message
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} | Consumer: {Name} {Id} | Message: {message.Id} {message.Data} |#thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

        Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
    }
}

// Usage
 var consumersDispatcher = new ConsumersDispatcher(1);
 Consumer consumer1 = new Consumer(1, "A");
 consumer1.Subscribe(consumersDispatcher);
 Consumer consumer2 = new Consumer(2, "B");
 consumer2.Subscribe(consumersDispatcher);
 Consumer consumer3 = new Consumer(3, "C");

 var consumersDispatcher1 = new ConsumersDispatcher(2);

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    var message = new Message(1, $"data {i}");
                    consumersDispatcher.OnMessageReceived(message);
                    continue;
                }

                var message1 = new Message(2, $"data {i}");
                consumersDispatcher1.OnMessageReceived(message1);
            }
```

2. "Message Dispatcher"

```
public class MessageDispatcher

{
    private List<Consumer> _consumers;

    public MessageDispatcher(List<Consumer> consumers)
    {
        _consumers = consumers;
    }

    public void Dispatch(Message message)
    {
        IEnumerable<Consumer> consumers = _consumers.Where(a => a.Messages.Any(x => x.Id == message.Id));

        Parallel.ForEach(consumers, c => c.Foo(message));
    }
}
```

3. Actor model (Akka.NET or Microsoft Orleans)

Conclusions

- If I go with events I will couple my objects (which I don't like) and as far as I know **DynamicInvoke()** use late binding which may be slow or may not (I have to do some performance tests).
- The second solution looks much slower than the first one.
- Actor model looks like exactly what I need. Each consumer has its own local queue and it's executed in parallel. The problem is that I haven't used any actor model and as far as I understood there are a lot of configurations (It should be configured for Kubernetes) and effort.

Can someone suggest me a more elegant solution?

Regards

Comment: Do you want this all to happen in-process?

Comment: What do you mean by "in-process" ?

Comment: in-process as in, the same process handles all the events. The other option is out-of-process where the consumers can run in another application/process so load can be balanced between resources.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your clarification. In my case, it should be in-process.

Comment: An excellent answer is given. Another option could be using [channels](https://dev.to/noseratio/c-events-as-asynchronous-streams-with-reactivex-or-channels-82k). Many options anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a good use case for the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow?view=net-5.0) library. It provides an actor-based programming model, but is more light-weight than Akka.NET or Microsoft Orleans. You can just create few built-in dataflow blocks by providing delegates for each consumer and link them together, providing filtering delegates. Each block has its own queue which you can configure. Everything works in-memory.

[Rx.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) is yet another alternative.

Comment: Hmm. It looks promising. I have to check it.